# Spring: force reload of a bean

Tags: java, spring, collections, javabeans, reload

I've been struggling with this for a while and it's driving me crazy.
Basically I've a bean defined as follows:

```
<bean id="tipoUfficioGiudiziarioListImpl" singleton="false"
    class="java.util.ArrayList" >
</bean>
```

and it's basically a collectio of all the entries in a table. now the problem is that this bean is loaded when at server start up (or at first use if I set `lazy-init="true"`) but if I add an entry on the db (both via the application itself or sql) the bean does not reload and I don't see the new entries when the collection is used.

is there any way to force this to reload or invalidate it so it'll be loaded at the next first use?

I'm using Spring 1.2

Comment: The real flaw, imho, is in the design. You have dymanic data (out of a database), and you map it to a single Spring object. Never going to work. Make a Spring bean that is a service able to get (and cache, and update) the data through a method call.

Comment: yeah I understand that, it's not my design... the ability to ad entries at runtime it's the feature I'm developing, before they were added directly via sql (and probably the server was restarted every time...). now of course I can manually load the list every time it's used but, I would prefer to keep things as simple as possible. thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you want to instantiate a new bean instance every time you use it, you can do this using prototype scope? `<bean id = tipoUfficioGiudiziarioListImpl"  class="java.util.ArrayList" scope = "prototype">`?

Comment: Itried but I got this error: `Attribute "singleton" must be declared for element type "bean"`

I guess it's because I'm using spring 1.2 instead of 2.x

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class DaoAspect {
    @Autowired
    TipoUfficioGiudiziarioListImpl impl;
    //your dao path,intercept your dao operation.
    @Before("execution(* com.test.dao..*.*(..))")
    public void doBeforeInServiceLayer(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        /*

           TODO  some condition

       */      
        impl.loaddata();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfurtunately I'm unable to skype at the moment :( can you at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: Ok,i try by writing.if you want reload,the spring has method to do it ,but it's a little unprofession.
you can write a method in "tipoUfficioGiudiziarioListImpl" that load the data.

Comment: yes, that I can do, but how do I store it replacing the old one? I'm already able to load "temporary" everytime is used, but what I would like to do is reload it when I add/edit/remove elements and forget about it.